# Icon for "mains" tag - warning sign

Tags: feature-request, tags

I was answering to this question:

[Connecting LEDs to 220v without using a power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140052/connecting-leds-to-220v-without-using-a-power-supply)

and I have an idea.

Other sites have images on some tags, like this one for "android" tag on Stack Overflow:

[image]

What if we could have something like this on (already existing) "mains" tag?

[image]

This is just ugly concept made in Paint to show what I mean. Im pretty sure that graphic designers who work on this site will draw more pretty warning sign, or maybe someone will post (16x18px?) graphic under my question.

It would work also as kind of "psychological warning" - be careful, this is dangerous.

**What you think about this?**

---

Edit/update:

I made better 18x16px icon.

[image]

Comment: Neat idea.  Worth a try.

Comment: Good idea - and worth using a similar icon in any answers or even adding it to questions when such risks are present.

Comment: Not sure if Stack Exchange have any policy on this but I think those images are sponsored tags so Google have probably paid for the icon. While I've never seen a sponsored tag here they might not like to confuse / dilute the sponsored tags with other tags but no harm asking.

Comment: @PeterJ yes, you're right: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/205264 - didn't know about that.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently 189 questions tagged with [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains). I really like the idea, but I'm afraid (not sure) that for every special tag icon, a SE team designer is needed, so if every site would ask it for tags with 200 questions, it would cost precious time.

**But** since it can work as a psychological warning as well, it may be worth a try - I like the idea.

While we're at it, we should as well think about these tags, as psychological warnings:

[high-voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-voltage), [high-current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-current), [high-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-power), [battery-charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) (?), [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino).

Comment: Psychological warning on arduiono? Seriously? But it might be good idea to think about other tags and add more icons - just for estetical purposes.

Comment: @Kamil to be honest, I don't think the designers have time to implement these icons everywhere. Arduino was pun-intended ;)

Comment: Yeah, the arduino icon would be a brain with at red circle and slash over it.

Comment: Oh, now I understand :)

Comment: I think it would be fine to have a warning but limit it to actual dangers.  High voltage is not always dangerous and is relative.  High current likewise.  Mains is a good thing to warn newcomers about an perhaps just one other tag that might just be a generic Hazard (with the same icon) tag for those things that are actually likely to pose a hazard EVEN IF instructions are followed, let seasoned editors add a hazard tag but only if required, mains tags when relevant.

Comment: @KalleMP I think a special tag would overcomplicate things. New users can add it to their questions as well if they don't understand, etc. As for my list: you're right that they're not always dangerous. I just wanted to suggest some :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm fine with the proposed "mains" tag with zap icon as long as it doesn't make us act like safety-nannies.

There is too much of trying to be the safety-police here already.  When someone asks *"How do I power my arduino shaving controller directly from line power without one of those expensive transformerators?"*, by all means point out the safety issues.  But, trying to close the question and adding "WARNING: SAFETY HAZARD" between every other sentence in your answer is going too far.  We can be clear that doing what is being asked about is dangerous, but being obnoxious and patronizing about it just noises up the site and makes us look like a bunch of weenies.

So yes, I'm for giving the new tag a try.  If it can deflect some of the excessive warning text, then fine.  If it encourages the holier-than-thou safety-nannies even more, then it should be removed.

Comment: It is better to look like bunch of weenies than let some 14 years old kid burn his house or kill himself. However I like that constructive criticism on my answer, maybe I went too deep into safety in that answer. +1

Comment: ... however too much criticism noises up the site too.